# Behavior of critical point of a dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm wondering about the following statement:

> Consider $f:E\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$, $f \in C^{1}(E)$, and the system
> $$\dot{x}= f(x)\hspace{10mm}(1)$$
> ans supose that $f(0)=0$, could you classify the qualitative behavior of statiotanary point $x=0$?

My attempt:
Consider the linearized system associated of (1), i.e.,

$$Df(0), \hspace{10mm} (2)$$

So we have the following cases

1. The eigen values have real part non zero, Thus from Hartman-Grobman we have that the behavior of (1) is ''equivalent'' to (2).

2.If only one eigenvalue of (2) have a real part zero, we can use the Central Manifold theory for analyze the behavior of (1).

3. if both eigen values have real part zero, we can have the center, focus or center-focus.

3a. If the system (1) is symmetric respcect to axis $x$ or $y$ the system is a center.

3b. If the system (1) is analytic, then the center is either the center or a focus.

3c. If (1) is an Hamiltonian system, we have a center. (The hamiltonian the critical points are saddles or centers.)

Could have more results in this case?  Thanks in advance!